# Skew product of Hilbert Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products, quantum-field-theory

I’m researching into relations of Fock spaces (in particular so-called “exponential types”) and in the book *Introduction to Algebraic and Constructive Quantum Field Theory* by Segal, Baez and Zhou they write that the antisymmitrised Fock space over a direct sum of 2 Hilbert spaces is isomorphic to the “skew product” of the antisymmitrised Fock spaces of both Hilbert spaces.

I’m not familiar with this operation of a skew product, it isn’t defined in the book explictely and I can’t find anything written on it in the context of Hilbert spaces. It carries the symbol of a tensor product symbol with a line underneath, that is: $ H_1 \underline{\otimes } H_2$ would denote the skew product of two Hilbert spaces $H_1$ and $H_2$.

Anybody know the definition of this operation?